# combining two mysql queries in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a dashboard to keep me updated on call agent status.an agent will have multiple records in the log. I need to pull the most recent status from the agent log.  The only way I have found is to query the agent table to pull the agents with status changes made today and then query the agent log table to pull the most recent status.

is there a way to combine the two queries.? Here are my queries

```
$sql_get_agents = "SELECT id FROM agent WHERE lastchange LIKE '{$today}%'";
            if($dta = mysql_query($sql_get_agents)){

                while($agent = mysql_fetch_assoc($dta)){
                $curr_agent[] = $agent;

                }

                foreach($curr_agent as $agents_online){
                    $get_status_sql = "SELECT a.firstname,a.lastname,al.agentid,al.agent_statusid,s.id as statusid,s.status,MAX(al.datetime) as datetime FROM agent_log al
                    INNER JOIN agent a ON al.agentid = a.id
                    INNER JOIN agent_status s ON a.agent_statusid = s.id
                    WHERE al.agentid = '{$agents_online['id']}'";
                    if($dta2 = mysql_query($get_status_sql)){                               
                        while($agent_status = mysql_fetch_assoc($dta2)){
                        $curr_status[] = $agent_status;                         
                        }
                    }

                }//end for each

                return $curr_status;
            }//end if
```

Comment: Use a JOIN. Never ever ever run queries in loops.

Comment: ...unless you're dealing with recursion in a so-called 'adjacency list' or similar

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you join the 2 queries into one adding the `WHERE lastchange LIKE '{$today}%'` condition in the second query?

Answer (score 0):

Using the IN clause should work :

```
"SELECT a.firstname,a.lastname,al.agentid,al.agent_statusid,s.id as statusid,s.status,MAX(al.datetime) as datetime FROM agent_log al
                    INNER JOIN agent a ON al.agentid = a.id
                    INNER JOIN agent_status s ON a.agent_statusid = s.id
                    WHERE al.agentid IN (SELECT id FROM agent WHERE lastchange LIKE '{$today}%');
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close with what you have.  This will get rid of the need to do both queries, or query in a loop.

**edit**: adding example code to loop over the results as well.

**edit2**: changed query.

```
$query = "SELECT 
   a.firstname,
   a.lastname,
   al.agentid,
   al.agent_statusid,
   s.id as statusid,
   s.status,
   MAX(al.datetime) as datetime 
FROM agent a
   LEFT JOIN agent_log al ON al.agentid = a.id
   LEFT JOIN agent_status s ON a.agent_statusid = s.id
WHERE a.lastchange LIKE '{$today}%'";

$status = array();
$results = mysql_query( $query );
while( $agent = mysql_fetch_assoc( $results ) )
    $status[] = $agent;

print_r( $status );
```

Comment: I tried that. it only returns one agent. I need it to return all 44 agents.

Comment: @AdamMills are you sure you're looping over the results?  Adding to my answer as an example...

Comment: yep. just returns one row. the row it returns has the most current date time stamp. I think the max is the problem.

Comment: odd.  try that updated query in the answer, that may work better for you.

Comment: I did. still only one row.

Comment: I found the problem. because MAX() is a group by function I needed to add a group by value.